Old Delphi app using SQL_ASCII, newer cloud version using UTF8,, but need both using same PostGres 16/17 data. Delphi 6 UTF8, issue., how to do it?
Interoperability suggestions.. legacy app Delphi 6 and Cloud version under development. UTF8 encoding has issue with Delphi. What Encoding may work on both. SQL_ASCII not supported for Postgres 16 or 17.
